# How to make TableViewDataSourcePrefetching with networking smooth?

Tags: swift

I can't seem to get my tableViewDataSourcePrefetching to run smoothly with my networking and Operation. Am I doing something wrong? Below is the table view methods. Im using a custom cell as well. Using an Operation where I'm converting the data from the images url from the web (using url session) and converting it to a UIImage from data and returning it in a completion closure as well as assigning it to a variable.

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

         if let imagesModel = imageController.viewModel(at: indexPath.row) {

            cell.images = imagesModel
            if let imageLoadOperation = imageLoadOperations[indexPath],
                let image = imageLoadOperation.image {

                    cell.picImageView.image = image

            } else {
                let imageLoadOperation = ImageLoadOperation(url: imagesModel.downloadUrl, completionHandler: { [weak self] (image) in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else {
                        return
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.picImageView.image = image
                    }
                    strongSelf.imageLoadOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
                })
                imageLoadQueue.addOperation(imageLoadOperation)
                imageLoadOperations[indexPath] = imageLoadOperation
            }
        }

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let imageLoadOperation = imageLoadOperations[indexPath] else {
            return
        }
        imageLoadOperation.cancel()
        imageLoadOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)

    }
}

extension ImagesTableViewController: UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {

        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            if let _ = imageLoadOperations[indexPath] {
                return
            }
            if let viewModel = imageController.viewModel(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) {
                let imageLoadOperation = ImageLoadOperation(url: viewModel.downloadUrl, completionHandler: {(image) in

                    })
                imageLoadQueue.addOperation(imageLoadOperation)
                imageLoadOperations[indexPath] = imageLoadOperation
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {

        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            guard let imageLoadOperation = imageLoadOperations[indexPath] else {
                return
            }
            imageLoadOperation.cancel()
            imageLoadOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)

        }
    }
```

Im trying to use a cache below:

```
    static func downloadImageFromUrl(_ url: String, completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {


        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }

        let cache =  URLCache.shared
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            if let data = cache.cachedResponse(for: request)?.data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(image)
                }
            } else {




        let task: URLSessionDataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    completionHandler(nil)
                    return
            }
            let cachedData = CachedURLResponse(response: response!, data: data)
            cache.storeCachedResponse(cachedData, for: request)

            completionHandler(image)
        })
        task.resume()
            }}

    }
}
```

Here is the Operation im using in my project:

```
class ImageLoadOperation: ConcurrentOperation {
    var url: String
    var completionHandler: ImageLoadOperationCompletionHandlerType
    var image: UIImage?

    init(url: String, completionHandler: ImageLoadOperationCompletionHandlerType) {
        self.url = url
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
    }

    override func main() {
        if isCancelled {
            return
        }

        UIImage.downloadImageFromUrl(url) { [weak self] (image) in
            guard let strongSelf = self,
                !strongSelf.isCancelled,
                let image = image else {
                    return
            }
            strongSelf.image = image
            strongSelf.completionHandler?(image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you caching the images?

Comment: hi, I tried but its not working, i'll update my questions to include the cache function.

Comment: Most likely that's your problem - your downloading the images over and over which creates lag and prevents smooth scrolling. Check out [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) it's really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. Do you see any reason why the cache above is not working for me? I will look into KingFisher, I've heard of it and I have used SDWebImage as well

Comment: Your cache code doesn't try to load the image from memory - it always starts a new task.

Comment: I changed the code now (posted above), but it still not working. Im following this guide: https://medium.com/swift2go/swiftbits-caching-images-9de11d034924 just for the image cache.

Comment: Well your code above doesn't show it using the cache to set the image it's using an imageOperation that isn't shown. Hard to help with incomplete information. Also you should describe what you're seeing - hard to know what you mean when you say "it doesn't work"

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip. This is my first time asking here. I have included the operation code as well. Again, when I load the app and scroll up/down it fetches but it lags and the images are not cached.